# Is it possible on gitlab ci build only on tag push event?

Tags: git, continuous-integration, gitlab, cdn

when I have a project with continuous integration gitlab at the time of making the push automatically tasks that are within the gitlab-ci.yml file are released , what I want is that only in time to make the push of a tag ( git push --follow -tags ) , the tasks of file gitlab-ci.yml - run , is this possible (only git push --follow -tags)?

[image]

I refer to this event , but with the build in gitlab ci.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Solved:

Add to `.gitlab-ci.yml` tags:

```
myjob:
  script: test
  only:
  - tags
```

Comment: A link to the [help page](https://gitlab.com/help/ci/yaml/README.md#onlyexcept-basic) may be helpful.

Comment: `only` and `except` have been deprecated.  Try using the [`rules` keyword](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rules).  For clarity, `only` and `except` still work for backwards compatability, but aren't being actively developed on.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment by Diggy, `only` and `except` have been deprecated. The equivalent with [`rules`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rules) is:

```yaml
myjob:
  script: test
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
```